# Why commutativity gives an invariant subspace?

Tags: cryptanalysis, block-cipher, lightweight

In [A Generic Approach to Invariant Subspace Attacks](https://www.iacr.org/archive/eurocrypt2015/90560155/90560155.pdf) the authors defined an invariant subspace as:
$$F(u + A) = v + A$$

Where $F:\mathbb{F}_2^n \to \mathbb{F}_2^n$,$u, v \in \mathbb{F}_2^n$,  and $A$ is a linear subspace.

Then they claimed that if $M\circ F = F\circ M$ for a linear subspace $M$ then $A:=ker\left(M+Id\right)$ is a linear subspace(**Lemma 2**).

I couldn't figure out why this is true for any bijective $F$ function. Any idea how to prove it?

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [math.se], as it seems to be pure linear algebra.